# Oracle APEX - how to show tooltip on a Link column of a report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a classic report with a link column on it and on click it executes javascript to open a pop up. I need to add tooltip to the link.

I know one way - to add `<span title="My tooltip text">#COLUMN_NAME#</span>` in Column Formatting, but that is only there for `Plain Text` columns.
I cannot make my column display only as it has to be a link as it's target is set to URL and calls javascript code.

If I change a column from link to `Plain Text` because it needs to call javascript and cramming all the javascript code into `<a href>` would be a problem because this way I cannot pass a column value to javascript:

```
SELECT '<a href="javascript:$s("P1_ITEM1",#FIELD1#);$("#POPUP_REGION").popup("open");">' || MyFunction(t1.id) || '</a>' my_field, t1.field1, t1.field2
FROM Table1 t1
```

The code above does not pass the value of FIELD1 column to javascript but instead puts it in as a string `#FIELD1#`.

So I am at loss how to do both - keep the link and show a tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this with the declarative Link target by supplying the title tag in the Link Attributes.

[image: APEX Link Target]

Note that my target is the item P310_ACTION_ID, and it's setting it with the column value in column alias ITEM_ID.

There will be a DA on that item to then invoke a popup, or whatever you need.

If you're doing it within SQL, you need to build the same string, something more like

```
<a title="blah" href="javascript:$s(''P1_ITEM1'','''||t.field1||''');">'||t.field1||'</a>'
```

Or if you're not a fan of fighting woodstock-style quotes, you can make things easier using a variation of

```
  apex_string.format(
     q'{<a title="blah" href=javascript:$s('%s','%s')}'
     ,'P1_ITEM1'
     ,t.field1
```

Comment: the solution was much more simple! I've noticed in attributes you had `title`, I've tried `alt` and `mouseover`. After I changed it to `title` it worked and I did not have to do anything more. Thank you!